# tshark - dump the data section

Tags: linux, protocols

As the name suggests, im trying to dump the data section of the packet,

man would suggest that its something like tshark -r file.pcap -t fields but im not having any luck

Comment: When you say not having any luck what do you mean? Do you get an error message, does it cause problems? What is the exact command you are using, on what OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

options are case sensitive, `-t` means format of timestamp and I guess you want to use -T that set the format of output. Depends on what kind of data you would like to dump, e.g., http host, `tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e http.host` should be what you are looking for.